# How to prepare .chm file from doxygen file with accented chars

Tags: encoding, doxygen, chm

I am making docs using doxygen with accented chars. I use the settings

```
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = ISO-8859-15
INPUT_ENCODING         = ISO-8859-15
```

to produce the HTML file. They are displayed OK. After that, my CMake file produces .chm file using commands

```
  add_custom_target(chm
    DEPENDS doc 
COMMAND chmcmd index.hhp
COMMAND chmod 755 ${PROJECT_NAME}.chm
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc
    COMMENT "Generating API documentation with chmcmd using Doxygen output"
    VERBATIM)
```

The charactersin the .chm file, however, are not accented, they show symptoms of wrong encoding. What additional setting shall I do?

Comment: Which problems do you run into when using UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-15? Also mention the version of doxygen you are using in your question.

Comment: @albert As I mentioned, the HTML pages are OK, so the problem is NOT with Doxygen. BTW: in the meantime I found that it makes no difference if I use UTF-8 or ISO-8859-15 in the configuration.

Comment: Sometimes chm reacts a bit different from HTML. Can you post a minimal code example with Doxyfile used (at least the difference between the standard Doxyfile and the one you used). Are you using the windows hhc.exe or another version? Which version of doxygen are you using and on which platform?